# How do I render my dropdown menu in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a functional component `Profile.js` and on the header of that screen I put a button. Once this button is pressed I want to display a dropdown menu from [react-native-material-menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-menu)

Part of my `Profile.js`:

```
function Profile(props) {

  useLayoutEffect(() => { 
          props.navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => <HeaderRight />,
          });
        } 
  }, []);
```

My `HeaderRight` component:

```
export const HeaderRight = () => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 20, marginRight: 8 }}>
      <Feather
        name="more-vertical"
        size={24}
        color="black"
        onPress={() => renderMenu()}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

As you can see when the icon is pressed I call my `renderMenu()`, which looks like the following:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { Menu, MenuItem, MenuDivider } from "react-native-material-menu";

export const renderMenu = (props) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  const hideMenu = () => setVisible(false);

  const showMenu = () => setVisible(true);

  return (
    <View
      style={{ height: "100%", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}
    >
      <Menu
        visible={visible}
        anchor={<Text onPress={showMenu}>Show menu</Text>}
        onRequestClose={hideMenu}
      >
        <MenuItem onPress={hideMenu}>Menu item 1</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onPress={hideMenu}>Menu item 2</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem disabled>Disabled item</MenuItem>
        <MenuDivider />
        <MenuItem onPress={hideMenu}>Menu item 4</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </View>
  );
};
```

When I render my page, I click on the header icon and I get the following error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Can you tell me, how do I render my dropdown menu component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not render the JSX on the return of an `onPress` function. Try this out:

```
export const HeaderRight = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  let toggle = () => setVisible(!visible);
  return (
    <>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 20, marginRight: 8 }}>
        <Feather
          name="more-vertical"
          size={24}
          color="black"
          onPress={toggle}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    <Menu
      visible={visible}
      anchor={<Text onPress={toggle}>Show menu</Text>}
      onRequestClose={toggle}>
        <MenuItem onPress={toggle}>Menu item 1</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onPress={toggle}>Menu item 2</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem disabled>Disabled item</MenuItem>
        <MenuDivider />
        <MenuItem onPress={toggle}>Menu item 4</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
     </>
  );
};
```